# What will be the post parameter when specifying vocabulary term?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-services

I am trying to create a drupal node with a iphone app via rest server. I want to send the request to drupal as json.

I have added a taxonomy vocabulary for categorizing the nodes. Specifying a category is mandatory when creating node.

> **My request url is**
>   drupal site/ep/node.json
>   
>   **Post parameters**
>   node[title]=mysample&node[type]=story&node[body]=sample body&node[???]=myCategory1

I specified title, body, and type....but **what will be the parameter name to specify the term of my vocabulary (i.e. category name)?**

I tried node[taxonomy], node[term], node[vocabulary], but no success. Please help!

> Config:
>   Drupal 6.26
>   REST Server 3.0

Answer (score 1):

in request URL not specified node.json only specified node.and use node[vocabulary term which u create][term name which u select];or  use node[vocabulary term which u create][term id]

Answer (score 0):

node[taxonomy][***vocabulary term id***][tid]=***vocabulary term id***

in place of ***vocabulary term id*** give the term id of the vocabulary term

How to get the term id? I made a custom drupal view of type term where I fetch only the fields **term id** and **term**

I then sent the view contents to my iphone app. When I choose a particular term I also have the term id.